# weird PHP filesize behavior

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite, filesize, fread

In the code below I...

1. open a textfile, write four characters to it, and close it again,
2. re-open it, read the contents, and use filesize to report the size of the file. (It's 4, as it should be),
3. manipulate those contents and tack on four more characters as well. Then I write that new string to the textfile and close it again,
4. use filesize again to report how big the file is.

To my surprise, the answer it gives is still 4 even though the actual size of the file is 8! Examining the contents of the file proves that the write works and the length of the contents is 8.

What is going on??

By the way I have to use fread and fwrite instead of file_get_contents and file_put_contents. At least I think I do. This little program is a stepping stone to using "flock" so I can read the contents of a file and rewrite to it while making sure no other processes use the file in between. And AFAIK flock doesn't work with file_get_contents and file_put_contents.

Please help!

```
<?php
$filename = "blahdeeblah.txt";

// Write 4 characters
$fp = fopen($filename, "w");
fwrite($fp, "1234");
fclose($fp);

// read those characters, manipulate them, and write them back (also increasing filesize).
$fp = fopen($filename, "r+");
$size = filesize($filename);
echo "size before is: " . $size . "<br>";
$t = fread($fp, $size);
$t = $t[3] . $t[2] . $t[1] . $t[0] . "5678";
rewind($fp);
fwrite($fp, $t);
fclose($fp);

// "filesize" returns the same number as before even though the file is larger now.
$size = filesize($filename);
echo "size after is: " . $size . "   ";

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php

**Note:** The results of this function are cached. See [clearstatcache()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) for more details.

Comment: Hooray! I knew it had to be some fussy detail. For Pete's sake if a programmer is using filesize multiple times in one script - as opposed to just using it once and assigning the value to a variable - then *obviously* it's because the filesize might change in between. Frickin' PHP.  Anyway, thanks CJ Dennis! You rock!

Comment: I think it makes sense to cache the file size. It's potentially an expensive call (especially if done over a network) and most files don't usually change size that often, if at all. There's nothing to stop bad programmers checking the same file over and over in a loop!

Comment: I hear you, but for me that kind of "feature" makes it so if a programmer who does make an expensive mistake like that might not ever learn why it's bad. It's tacitly giving approval to sloppy coding. But hey, I guess there's a reason people - including me - learned to use languages other than C.  Thanks again, CJ Dennis.

Comment: For caching `filesize()` I'd vote 80% yes and 20% no. I can see both the pros and cons but I believe the pros outweigh the cons. What if you check the file size in two unrelated classes? It would be cumbersome to pass a variable in just to cache the size between them(don't even mention `global`!) It's easier to let PHP cache the sizes for you. Bad programmers will always find a way of writing bad code no matter how strict/restrictive the language is! Bad programmers don't care or need more education or shouldn't be programmers. It's beyond our power to stop that!

Comment: LOL! You make a cogent argument CJ Dennis :-)

Answer (score 1):

When you open a file by fopen() function you can obtain **proper size at any time** using fstat() function:

```
$fstat=fstat($fp);
echo 'Size: '.$fstat['size'];
```

Example:

```
$filename='blahdeeblah.txt';

$fp=fopen($filename, 'a');

$size=@filesize($filename);
echo 'Proper size (obtained by filesize): '.$size.'<br>';

$fstat=fstat($fp);
echo 'Proper size (obtained by fstat): '.$fstat['size'].'<br><br>';

fwrite($fp, '1234');
echo 'Writing 4 bytes...<br><br>';

$fstat=fstat($fp);
echo 'Proper size (obtained by fstat): '.$fstat['size'].'<br>';

fclose($fp);

$size=@filesize($filename);
echo 'Wrong size (obtained by filesize): '.$size;
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that cached value is used only in current script. When you run the script again filesize() reads new (proper) size of file.
Example:

```
$filename='blahdeeblah.txt';

$fp=fopen($filename, 'a');

$size=@filesize($filename);
echo 'Proper size: '.$size.'<br>';

fwrite($fp, '1234');
fclose($fp);

$size=@filesize($filename);
echo 'Wrong size: '.$size;
```